# jQuery Text in in hidden DIV showing as a blank string

Tags: jquery

I'm not sure why the following wouldn't be working.  I am getting a blank string when I attempt to retrieve the text from the FirstName textbox in my HTML.  The DIV is currently hidden, would that make any difference?  Any ideas?

jQuery:

```
 $.ajax({ url: 'go.aspx?FirstName=' + $("#FirstName").text()});
```

HTML:

```
<input name="FirstName" type="text" id="FirstName" style="width:240px;" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/):

```
$.ajax({ url: 'go.aspx?FirstName=' + $("#FirstName").val()});
```

Additionally, if all you are doing is that simple call, you might want to use `$.get` instead:

```
$.get('go.aspx', { 'FirstName':$("#FirstName").val() });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the val for the value of input fields
    $("#FirstName").val()

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({ url: 'go.aspx?FirstName=' + $("#FirstName").val()});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the val() method instead of text().

http://api.jquery.com/text/

http://api.jquery.com/val/

Edit: You've gotta be fast at this place...

Answer (score 0):

`.val()` is the jQuery function you want.

see

http://api.jquery.com/val/